# Getting 'The 'location' attribute is not allowed" in App.Config while saving log info to a text file

Tags: vb.net, logging, visual-studio-2015, app-config

I want to record the user activity in the Application.Log file so that I can check what he/ she did before any error occurred or simply check if any wrong activity is done by the user. First, to get record the activity I read the article '[How to: Write Log Messages (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/how-to-write-log-messages)' from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/)'s documentation website and changed the appropriate value according to my need. It was all good, I was getting the information successfully in the **Debug Output** but when I wanted to save this to a text file then I encountered a problem. I followed the instruction given in the article '[How to: Write Event Information to a Text File (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/how-to-write-event-information-to-a-text-file)' from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/)'s documentation website.
The code written on the website to save log information to a text file is:

```
<add name="FileLogListener"   
    type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener,   
          Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  
    initializeData="FileLogListenerWriter"  
    location="Custom"  
    customlocation="c:\temp\" />
```

All code mentioned above seems fine and no error is shown except the two `location` and `customlocation`, which throws an error **Message**,

> - The '`location`' attribute is not allowed.
> - The '`customlocation`' attribute is not allowed.

I tried a lot but can't solve this error. I have found an interesting note on that documentation site. It says the following.

> **ⓘ Note**
>
> To set the value of a listener property, use an attribute that has the same name as the property, with all letters in the name lowercase. For example, the **`location`** and **`customlocation`** attributes set the values of the [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.location) and [CustomLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener.customlocation) properties.

But I was failed to solve the error even by reading information given in these websites.

Please help!

Comment: I just tried what you did and I don't see any errors. I do see warnings on those two attributes but the project builds without issue. Have you tried building and running the project to see whether it actually works? It may well be that that note is referring to the fact that you can set a property of any type derived from `TraceListener` that way, even though the configuration system doesn't recognise them explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. There is no problem on building and running the project but it doesn't work. I mean I don't get any outputs. :( Did you got the output btw?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may not have your config file quite right.  I followed a link from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/how-to-write-event-information-to-a-text-file) to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/working-with-application-logs) and copied the config example into my app.  I then went back to the other page and modified my config file based on that.  I then ran my app, which had the default name of 'ConsoleApp1', and I did indeed see the file 'ConsoleApp1.log' written to the specified folder with the appropriate information.  Here's what my final config file looked like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
  </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLogListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLogListener"
           type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
           initializeData="FileLogListenerWriter"
           location="Custom"
           customlocation="D:\johnm\Documents\" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

and here's my VB code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        TracingTest(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "LogFile.txt"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TracingTest(ByVal fileName As String)
        My.Application.Log.WriteEntry($"Entering TracingTest with argument '{fileName}'.")

        ' Code to trace goes here.

        My.Application.Log.WriteEntry($"Exiting TracingTest with argument '{fileName}'.")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Does it matter if I have a multiple .config file? Like other .config file to do this job other than app.config? Because it seems I coded everything similar to what you said and after reading your answer I changed everything according I guess. And  one question in your answer you used two different paths, one "D:\johnm\Documents\" and the other is the User Documents folder. So is it like the actual log file is being created on the first location "D:/"?

Comment: The path used in the VB code is irrelevant because that's just treated as a `String` argument in that method. It's never actually treated as a file path.  I just used a file path because the parameter name implied it. Also, "D:\johnm\Documents\" is the User Documents folder in this case. I moved all my data libraries to my D: drive and use my C: drive only for the OS and applications.

Comment: I have no idea whether having multiple config files would matter. If it did, as long as this was in the main one then I would think that you should be good to go.

Comment: Damn.. Entering it in the main 'App.config' file solved the issue and I am getting the log but I wonder why entering on the second config file doesn't work. Please can you explain me that it will be helpful to understand the error. AND THANKSSS A LOT!!! You helped me thrice in a row mannn I am so thankful to you... [No words to express the feeling]

Comment: Please add that using it in the main .config file so that I can accept your answer as solved.